# How to get line information in search function which line i found the string i am looking for?

Tags: c++, string, fstream

```
#include <string>
 #include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
 using namespace std;

 int search(string pat, string txt)

{
int M=(int)pat.length();
int N=(int)txt.length();
int occurences=0;

for (int s=0; s<=N-M; s++)
{
    int j;
    for (j=0; j<M; j++)
    {
        if (txt[s+j]!= pat[j])

            break;

    }
    if (j==M)
    {
        occurences++;
    }   
}return occurences;
}
  int main()

  {
string pat;
string txt;
int line = 1;

cout << "Pattern: ";
cin >> pat;
cout << endl;

ifstream infile("/Users/irem/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/sample2.txt");

while (getline(infile, txt))
{
    cout << "Line " << line << ": " << search(pat, txt) << " occurences" << endl;
    line++;
}
  return 0;
```

}

my code perfectly read the file and search for a given string in the text file.But i want the information that which line how many occurrences while search function making string matching?Line information always stay at 1.

Comment: Can you please post a complete example that we could compile on our own?

Comment: @nomatterhowitried Edit your question and post the code there. Not in the comment

Comment: I did. Now can you help? @Sniper

Comment: What line ending is used in your input file? How long is line 2? To be honest I'm having problems to understand your "error description". How many lines of output does your program generate? Are there several lines where the line number is always 1? Or do you only have one loop execution?

Comment: post the content of file, or some info about it

Comment: My guess is that there could be a problem with line ending as @starturtle mentioned. \r\n is used in DOS/Windows systems, \n is used in *Nix system. Try to open the file in some kind of hexeditor.